# Expression parser for Predicates in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, parsing, jpa, boolean-expression

In a command line based application I want to offer basic support for filtering database results. For this, I need to parse user input. I want to support these tokens:

- boolean (logical) operators including `and`, `or`, `not` and parentheses
- variables, strings, dates and numbers
- comparison Operators: `=`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`

So an input string could look like this:

*(age > 3 or name != 'tom') and city='london' and ((birthday=01.01.2010 or birthday >= 01.01.2013))*

Basic stuff.

**Question**: Where do I get a (tokenizer and) parser for that?

- Are there libraries supporting these basics already?
- If not, I know that there are tools to generate Java classes for Tokenizers and Parsers. Do you have any recommendations?

I would then convert the results to JPA's `Predicate`s for the `CriteriaQuery`. First I thought, I could just offer JPQL in command line and let the user specify SQL based restrictions. But I don't want to let the user write conditions that might stop working e. g. when the database schema changes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "I could just offer JPQL in command line and let the user specify SQL based restrictions.". Why don't you let users specify JPQL restrictions?

Comment: I want to provide a stable interface. If I'd let the user write restrictions in JPQL, he'd have to rewrite them whenever the model changes. Conditions in an intermediate language would have to be interpreted where variables could be remapped to the up-to-date model. Besides, these expressions might come into play in another, non JPQL context in the future.

Comment: @JBNizet All the expression frameworks (like JUEL, MVEL, JEXL, ...) are able to parse Strings into Expression instances and evaluate them. I don't need the evaulation as this will be done later by JPA and the DBMS. I'd need to transform (boolean) expressions from some expression language into JPA `Predicate`s. The question is: Which framework supports this or is there even one that already has something like it (`expression.transform(CriteriaQuery.class)` or maybe `expression.transform(new MyExpressionTransformer()`).

Comment: My question is: why don't you just use JPQL? The above query looks a lot like a JPQL where clause. Prepend `"select person from Person person where "` to the above, and you have a JPQL query that you can execute directly.

Comment: @JBNizet Also see my first comment, where you find the answer to your question. But I'm also afraid that I'd expose too much to the user. Have a look at this: `select * from user_comments where comment in (select password as comment from admin)`

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for some tokenizer and parser.

ANTLR is a lexer/parser generator, and the huge grammar repository that also, among others, contains SQL - even with dialects for some common databases at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql.

So if you still have that problem, you can generate the parser for free and just care about translating the abstract syntax tree into JPA criteria calls.

Comment: I'm not searching explicitly for an SQL grammar. I'm just searching for a grammar that handles conditions. So the Github page would be extremely helpful, if they had some sort of examples for each grammar in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.

Comment: Under each language directory in [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) is an "examples/" directory, e.g., [grammars-v4/arithmetic/examples](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/arithmetic/examples), which contains examples for each grammar. What you want is an expression grammar. You can start from an [arithmetic expression grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/39e35769d4e8d66fe5989e458ac0caedb8a92fd2/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4#L41), or copy the rules for expressions in one of the many other grammars, then modify it to your needs.